# Каков смысл предложения?

Tags: смысл, редактура

> Наша клиника создавалась для решения самых сложных задач, которые
>   связаны с вопросами бесплодия, снижения веса, борьбы со стрессом и
>   Anti-age направлением.

Как правильно понимать предложение, а именно последнюю его часть?
Есть два варианта:

1. Слово *борьба* связано и *со стрессом и с Anti-age направлением*, потому что они стоят после него. То есть смысл предложения получается таким, что клиника создана для борьбы со стрессом и борьбы с Anti-age направлением.
2. Слово *борьба* связано только *со стрессом*, потому что это предложение можно можно разбить на два простых.

Наша клиника создавалась для решения самых сложных задач, которые связаны с вопросами бесплодия, снижения веса, борьбы со стрессом.
Наша клиника создавалась для решения самых сложных задач, которые связаны с Anti-age направлением.

В таком случае неправильно говорить, что клиника создавалась для борьбы с Anti-age направлением.

Answer (score 1):

Понятно, что хотели сказать, но сказали именно про **борьбу** с *направлением Anti-age* (в русском обычно такой порядок следования видового наименования и названия). Исправить можно двумя способами:

- перенести последний перечисляемый элемент ближе к началу (если это не нарушает задуманную расстановку элементов в порядке значимости)
- повторить обобщающие слова: "*и задач, связанных* с направлением Anti-age"

Answer (score 0):

Грамматическая связь управление (в данном случае Т.падежом) будет отнесена к ближайшему  слову, которое может считаться главным: **борьбы  (с чем?) со стрессом и Anti-age направлением**, в то время как автор хотел  сказать **про решение задач ,  которые связаны (с чем?) с  Anti-age направлением.**

Поэтому предложение стилистически некорректно, его нужно редактировать, например:

(1) Наша клиника создавалась для решения самых сложных задач, которые связаны с такими вопросами, **как  бесплодие, снижение веса, борьба со стрессом, Anti-age направление.**

(2) Или: Наша клиника создавалась для решения самых сложных задач,  т**аких как  бесплодие, снижение веса, борьба со стрессом, Anti-age направление.**

(3) Или: Наша клиника создавалась для решения таких сложных задач, **как  бесплодие, снижение веса, борьба со стрессом, Anti-age направление.**

Answer (score 0):

Получилось, что клиника создавалась для борьбы с Anti-age направлением.
На мой взгляд, нужно перенести Anti-age направление, а заодно избавиться от ненужного канцеляризма "задачи, которые связаны с вопросами". Также желательно при перечислении не смешивать проблемы и способы их решения ("бесплодие и  борьба со стрессом" заменить на "лечение бесплодия и борьба со стрессом").

**Наша клиника создавалась для решения самых сложных задач, связанных с лечением бесплодия, снижением веса, Anti-age направлением и борьбой со стрессом.**

Comment: 1) Названы четыре задачи, но, возможно, есть и другие. 2) Связанных с направлением -  это как?

Comment: @Jasmin, Названы не задачи, а темы (направления исследований), задачи звязаны с этими темами (направлениями). Ваше замечание неясно сформулировано. Что тут неверно? "Задачи, связанные с определенным направлением (исследований)" — корректно, по-моему. Что-то еще под вопросом?

Comment: Может быть, и корректно, но я этот перечень как-то негативно воспринимаю. Мне  не нравится, что он ограниченный  (4 темы) и с замыкающим союзом И. Не нравится порядок перечисления, Anti-age направление почему на третьем месте? Лучше его отправить в конец в связи с особенной графикой.

Comment: @Jasmin, Судя по стилю оригинала, я думаю, что список именно закрытый. Если на деле это не так, то лучше использовать Ваш подход (поставить "такие как" перед перечислением). Нo если список закрытый, то избежать двусмысленности удается, только если поместить борьбу в  конец списка.